# I am trying to put some border to my cross text in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to give some border to my cross text which around 45 degree in excel but issue is that whenever i apply border to cross text the border also get apply at 45 degree.

I am looking for a straight rectangle border which contains cross text in it in excel.

Please help me to do that

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can find a way around that, but you could improvise;

try removing all the borders on that particular cell then sort of draw a rectangle (Or similar shape) and set its fill to nothing so it can give this impression of a "straight border" and this will look good, if you format it well that is, on printed paper.

Or you can draw a textbox on top of the cell (with the same size) and remove any color fill

If there's an option of locking its position, it would be useful too